# How to close facebook feed dialog popup on click of cancel button without help of redirect url?

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I want to close facebook feed dialog popup on click of cancel button.

**Without redirect URL**

I want to implement it in angularjs.!
I have feed dialog as shown in image.

I have to close dialog shown in image on click of **Cancel** button. But without help of redirect URL. (As it is not possible in my case to change URL)

[Please click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cA8y.png)

Comment: could you show us some example..exactly what you want?

Comment: Please check I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3#jssdk)'s feed dialog.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){});
```

Comment: Above code is not related Cancel button  it is just " for triggering a Feed Dialog using the FB.ui function with a feed method parameter"